# Windows Phone 7 finding a URL in a string from Twitter API and making it clickable

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

Trying to find the sexiest way to receive a "tweet" from the twitter API and find any urls that may exist in it and then making those links "clickable" inside the displayed tweet.  Was thinking of doing it exactly as the official twitter app does it when you click on a tweet and go to the page that details that particular tweet and the url inside the tweet is bold and blue and clickable....

example of the data I'm working with...

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Not sure if I should take the string that is returned and parse through it to find something starting with "http:" or "https:" or if I should loop through the URL array that is returned in the tweet object from twitter (in which case I would then need to find the same string in the message string and change it into a link anyway)...

Also, which control should I use for the link, should I programmatically insert a button into the textblock?  Is there a way to make part of a textblock clickable?

I know there is an elegant and simple solution to this that I'm missing.  My layout is below:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pageBackground.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding profile_image_url}" Height="83" Width="83" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <StackPanel Width="371">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#066d96" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding screen_name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#066d96" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Name="tbText" Foreground="#211F20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding age}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#fabb69" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Padding="0 10 0 0"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for the non-Twitter API parts, but if you set Twitter's `include_entities` parameter to `true`, `t`, or `1` (as detailed on the documentation page you linked to), you'll get a pre-parsed representation of the tweet back.

If you look at the example in the documentation, `entities` is an object containing a `urls` array. Each object in the `urls` array is a URL. The `indices` array in the URL object contains the starting and ending index of the URL in the tweet text.

Comment: I guess we're just supposed to use Buttons for links, right?  Just take off the border?

Comment: @Jarrette: As I said, I don't know anything about Windows Phone 7. Sorry.